# Onepage navigation and scrolling effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm building a one-page website for a client, basically it's multiple `<section>` all in `display:none;` except the one currently browsed, and you switch views using the header menu.

```
 $('header a').click(function(){
                var target = $(this).attr('href');
                $("#content > .visible").css('display', 'none').removeClass('visible');
                $(target).css('display', 'block').addClass('visible');
 });
```

So it works like a charm, but my client asked me to add a scrolling effect when you change the view... 
With this current configuration I don't know how to deal with it using my `display:none;` system, and it would really bother me to have to rewrite my navigation system...

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: yes, if you want a scrolling page then don't hide the sections and use anchor tags with animation instead...

Comment: Yes, but I would like my others sections to not be viewable by "natural" scroll, how could I do that ?

Comment: I don't understand.. do you mean you want a to be able to scroll sections through the navigation but to not have a scrollbar?

Comment: I think you can do that with having the scrollable area in a container with overflow:hidden, and then scroll it with code..

Comment: Thank you webkit, I managed to do what I needed using your method.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for your **one-page scrolling website.**

- [Github repo](https://github.com/alvarotrigo)
- [Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: It looks **very** nice, i'll give it a try for another client, but I'm now in a hurry, and it would be too much work to rebuild the website using it (too much relative positionning in my code, i tried to use it and it messed up my design) ..  But it's exactly the kind of effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution using jQuery. There are some built in functions called "hide" and "show" that you can pass parameters to. You should be able to change your code to this:

```
$('header a').click(function(){
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#content > .visible").hide(1000).removeClass('visible');
            $(target).show(1000).addClass('visible');
});
```

the 1000 is milliseconds. If you want something a little more involved, the .animate function has more options than .hide and .show.